# Child application doesn't start when run from windows scheduled task

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule an automation script.

The 
1. .bat file starts monitor script (python)
2. monitor script (python) does network request for jobs from other system
3. if job, monitor script (python) starts UI automation script (python)
4. UI automation script (python) starts the "Target GUI Application".

When running the `.bat` manually, (2), (3), and (4) execute as expected and the GUI Application starts.

However, when the `.bat` file is called from within the *windows scheduler* task context (2), (3) starts but is unable to *start* the GUI Application.

Tried to enable the "Run with highest privileges" option for the task, but this didn't change anything.

How can I get the child application to start from within the "windows scheduler task" context?

> using pywinauto `Application()` to start the GUI Application.